# How can you submit departure date and transit mode to google map direction?

Tags: google-maps

Actually I have a form that use the Place API to determine the right address for start address and arrival address

```
<section class="itineraire section">
    <h2 class="sectiontitle"><?php _e( 'Itinéraire', 'mlog_regim' ); ?></h2>
    <form method="get" action="https://www.google.com/maps/" target="https://www.google.com/maps/">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="saddr" type="text" id="saddr" class="form-control" placeholder="Adresse de départ" onFocus="geolocate()" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="daddr" type="text" id="daddr" class="form-control" placeholder="Adresse d'arrivée">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="txtDate" type="date" id="txtDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Date'">
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="travel_mode" value="3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Rechercher</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

And I would like to force the google map to display travel_mode 3 (transit) and the date to be set at the txtDate value. I can't find in the doc how to do it, but I've found some website that do it and it look not that hard... Do someone could give me some advice ?

[Go Transit](http://www.gotransit.com/public/en/schedules/google.aspx)

[RTC Quebec (Your itinerary)](http://rtcquebec.ca/Default.aspx?tabid=56&language=en-CA)

Fill the form with theses inforamtion

Start point : 2220 Boulevard Pie-IX, Montréal, QC H1V 2E2, Canada

End point : Pointe-aux-Trembles, Montréal, QC, Canada

Choose any random date... for Go Transit, RTC Quebec only prove the travel mode.

Thank's for anyone help it will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected parameters are

- `dirflg` set it to `r` for public transport
- `date`     format: `mm/dd/yyyy`
- `time`       format: `hh:mm`
- `ttype`  set it to `dep`(departure) or `arr`(arrival)

example:

```
<form method="get" action="https://www.google.com/maps/" target="google-maps">
  <br/>
  <input name="saddr" placeholder="origin" value="2220 Boulevard Pie-IX, Montréal, QC H1V 2E2, Canada" />
  <br/>
  <input name="daddr" placeholder="destination" value="Pointe-aux-Trembles, Montréal, QC, Canada" />
  <br/>
  <input name="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />
  <br/>
  <input name="time" placeholder="hh:mm" />
  <br/>
  <select name="ttype">
    <option value="dep">departure</option>
    <option value="arr">arrival</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="dirflg" value="r" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xnn34qL1/